GA4 - Custom Item Scoped Dim capturing value "1" and not string
GTM preview shows the parameter is correctly capturing and the dim is registered in GA4, but only a value of 1 is appearing. The parameter is also passed correctly when observing through GA4 debug.
Any thoughts?
Image of parameter setup and capture
Tag Setup
PDP View Event 
PDP View Event Values
Debug View
Implemented Item scoped custom dimension capturing a string, however only a value of 1 is appearing.

Can you show the tag how you set it? Or the preview screenshot when it triggered.

@darrelltw, thanks for you help I've updated the original post with more screenshots

From what I see in your setting.
The c_badgetext is an Event Parameter in your tag setting.
But at the custom dimension you set as the Item Scope.

Event parameter is different than item scope parameter.
Event parameter is along with the Event
Item scope parameter is following the Item

So what we need to find out is the c_badgetext should follow item or event?
If it's a item scope parameter. You need to put it within the items.
Here is an example of how to set custom parameter within an item.

